# Why does PHP running as FCGI need to spawn multiple children?

Tags: php, fastcgi

What is the benefit of this, versus launching just one?

Comment: so whats an optimal amount on a shared host, if you have 2 or 3 active domains?

Answer (score 4):

To allow you to process multiple concurrent PHP requests.